# NativeScript-Vue [node-rsa] TypeError: util.inherits is not a function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-cli

When trying to include **`node-rsa`** got:

> `TypeError: util.inherits is not a function.`

Repro steps:

```
vue init nativescript-vue/vue-cli-template repro
cd repro
npm install --save node-rsa
npm install
```

Add this line to `HelloWorld.vue`:

```
<script>
```

> import * as NodeRSA from "node-rsa"; // add this line

```
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        surprise: false,
      };
    },
  };
</script>

npm run watch:ios
```

Got this error:

```
***** Fatal JavaScript exception - application has been terminated. *****
Native stack trace:
1   0x104692c1f NativeScript::reportFatalErrorBeforeShutdown(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::Exception*, bool, bool)
2   0x1046c7caf -[TNSRuntime executeModule:referredBy:]
3   0x10414b441 main
4   0x10a137955 start
5   0x1
JavaScript stack trace:
1   @file:///app/app.js:13604:14
2   __webpack_require__@file:///app/app.js:20:34
3   @file:///app/app.js:36341:33
4   @file:///app/app.js:36601:34
5   __webpack_require__@file:///app/app.js:20:34
6   @file:///app/app.js:36311:33
7   __webpack_require__@file:///app/app.js:20:34
8   @file:///app/app.js:9649:30
9   __webpack_require__@file:///app/app.js:20:34
10  @file:///app/app.js:27449:30
11  @file:///app/app.js:27838:34
12  __webpack_require__@file:///app/app.js:20:34
13  @file:///app/app.js:27406:35
14  __webpack_require__@file:///app/app.js:20:34
15  @file:///app/app.js:27228:176
16  __webpack_require__@file:///app/app.js:20:34
17  @file:///app/app.js:13948:38
18  __webpack_require__@file:///app/app.js:20:34
19  @file:///app/app.js:63:37
20  anonymous@file:///app/app.js:64:12
21  evaluate@[native code]
22  moduleEvaluation@[native code]
23  @[native code]
24  promiseReactionJob@[native code]
JavaScript error:
file:///app/app.js:13604:14: JS ERROR TypeError: util.inherits is not a function. (In 'util.inherits(assert.AssertionError, Error)', 'util.inherits' is an instance of Object)
```